# Get the first empty select box recursively

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple `select` boxes in my document and some of them are load with page load and some of them created dynamically.  for example:

```
<select>
    <option>select one</option>
</select>

<select></select>

<select>
    <option>select two</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option>select three</option>
</select>

<select>
</select>
```

and more are created dynamically some of with  and some are empty.

I want to get the first empty `select` among them at page load and click on a button again want to get the first empty `select` box ***from the last one I get*** and continue this until no such `select` box further exists.

#### NOTE *from the last one means*,

If I get the first empty `select` box from first, then one `button` click search will start from that `select` box and continue until again get an empty `select` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('select:empty:first');
```

but one think to note that, above selector only works if your `select` box are like

```
<select></select> // even without any newline
```

because `:empty` point element with no child, not event with newline or text node.

So if your `select` is look like:

```
<select>
</select>
```

above selector will fail. To get `select` like both type you can use

```
$('select').filter(function() {
  return !this.innerHTML.replace(/\s/g,'').length;
}).first();
```

or as @gdoron mentioned

```
$('select').filter(function() {
  return !$.trim(this.innerHTML);
}).first();
```

In my choice, second one is reliable.

```
// solution to your recursive search

$('select')
    .filter(function() { // filtering for empty select
        return !this.innerHTML.replace(/\s/g,'').length;
     })
    .first() // taking the first
    .addClass('lastIndentified'); // adding a class to keep track

$('button#search').on('click', function() {
  // reference for last empty select
  var lastIndentified = $('select.lastIndentified');

  lastIndentified
      .nextAll('select') // searching for all select
      .filter(function() { // making filtering
           return !this.innerHTML.replace(/\s/g,'').length;
      })
      .first() // taking first one from lastIndetified
      .addClass('lastIndentified');
    lastIndentified.removeClass('lastIndentified'); // remove class from last empty select and pass it to new empty select

    // for example
    // calling function to process with last empty select
    processWithLastEmptySelect($('select.lastIndentified'));
});

function processWithLastEmptySelect(lastSelect) {
   // your code if needed
   lastSelect.css('border', '1px solid green');
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/48/)**

Comment: I would use my way, or with `trim`. `$('select').filter(function() {
  return !$.trim(this.innerHTML);
  
})`

Comment: I didn't use `length`... you can remove it. the empty string is a "falsy" value.

Comment: No problem, we are here to learn.(and compete with @Jon Skeet...)

Answer (score 3):

As @thecodeparadox answered you allready, this is a valid option:

```
$('select:empty:first')
```

But `:empty`  selects only elements that don't have any child nodes, including **textnodes**,  so

```
<select> </select>
        ^------------------text node
```

or

```
<select> <--------- text node
</select>
```

are not empty and the `:empty` selector won't grab them.

If you have one of those, you can use this selector:

```
// Select the first <select> that doesn't have an option as a child.
$('select:not(:has(option))').first()....
```

---

`jQuery(':empty')` [**docs**](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)

> **Description**: Select all elements that have no children (**including text nodes**).